# Get first date of current month in MacOS terminal

Tags: macos, shell, date

uisng the command `echo $(date "+%F" -d "$(date +'%Y-%m-01') 0 month")` i can get the first date of that month. but the same is not working on mac terminal. What needs to be changed?

```
echo $(date "+%F" -d "$(date +'%Y-%m-01') 0 month")
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

Comment: Why echo and `$(..)`, you can run just `date` in the terminal - `date "+%F" -d "$(date +'%Y-%m-01') 0 month"`

Comment: [BSD date](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?date) is not [GNU date](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html). `What needs to be changed?` The date program you are using.

Comment: yeah you cna remove those echo and $(..). I am having issue running this on a mac terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `date` libraries in *BSD and GNU systems are different and the options supported vary between them. The `-d` flag which supports a myriad of functions in GNU date is replaced by the `-f` option in BSD (See [FreeBSD Manual Page](http://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?date) for date)

For your requirement though, you need the time adjust flag using the `-v` flag. So the first day of the current month should be

```
date -v1d -v"$(date '+%m')"m '+%F'
```

- The `-v1d` is a time adjust flag to move to the first day of the month
- In `-v"$(date '+%m')"m`, we get the current month number using `date '+%m'` and use it to populate the month adjust field. So e.g. for Aug 2020, its set to `-v8m`
- The `'+%F'` is to print the date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. If its not supported in your date version, use `+%Y-%m-%d` explicitly.

Or if your requirement is to print the date for all the months

```
for mon in {1..12}; do
    date -v1d -v"$mon"m '+%F'
done
```